# How to verify number of rows using Selenium after applying pagination in table?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to write a test case in selenium, where I have to set pagination to 10 and confirm that the number of records displayed after setting pagination is also 10. But whatever I try end up giving the same value as 1. But I should get the answer as 10.

[image]

I tried using `size()` function against the table id. But it ends up giving value as 1.

```
String ExpectedNumberOfRecordsBasedOnPagination="10";
Pagination.selectByVisibleText(ExpectedNumberOfRecordsBasedOnPagination);

WebElement VehicleNumberTable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='tableforsearchResultsEMI']/tbody"));
List<WebElement>ListOfRecordsBasedOnPagination=VehicleNumberTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
int ActualNumberOfRecordsBasedOnPagination=ListOfRecordsBasedOnPagination.size();
System.out.println("Scenario 10 Pass: When the user sets the Pagination to a certain number: "+ExpectedNumberOfRecordsBasedOnPagination 
    +" Then the table values should display the same number of records:" +ActualNumberOfRecordsBasedOnPagination );
```

Expected value is 10. But I am getting 1.

Comment: Can you post another screenshot of how many <tr> you have within the <tbody>

Comment: can you share url if possible in public?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sure that all 10 rows are under tbody? I can see only the first tr in the screenshot, can you share the first 3 rows screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried using the length property, as in ListOfRecordsBasedOnPagination.length

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs.
It worked after I added a **thread.sleep()** between the pagination function and counting rows function

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of Thread.sleep(), better way is to wait for the **label("1 of 10")** and then validate the number of rows.

Comment: I am new to selenium. Can you give me the code snippet for the same so I can use it in my code. Sorry for the trouble